# Generalized theorem of Arzela Ascoli

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, compactness, equicontinuity

Let $Z$ be a Banach-space and $A \subset Z$ compact and $X$ be another Banach-space.
How can I now show that

$M \subset C(A;X)$ is pre-compact in $C(A;X)$ if and only if $M$ is equicontinuous and for all $t \in A$ the set $M(t)=\{v(t) \in X : v \in M \}$ is  pre-compact in $X$.

How to begin?

Comment: Are you sure it is $C(A;X)$ rather than $L(A;X)$? Also what is the original topology on $C(A;X)$? The uniform topology? And, is the weak topology on $C(A;X)$ induced by $(C(A;X))^*$ as usual?

Comment: I haven't addressed this topic for a long time. Is the weak topology on  $C(A,X)$ generated by the sub-base of all $\{g: \|g(a)-f(a)\|<r\}$ over all $f\in C(A,X),$ all $a\in A,$  and all $r>0$? If so, I can show you a few things to get going.

Comment: Maybe this hints makes some things more clear, I am not sure:

Weak compactness and total boundedness in complete metric spaces are equivalent. First I should show that there exists a countable dense subset in $A$..

Comment: @Tesla then I think you might have confused "weak compactness" with pre-compactness (which means the closure is compact).

Comment: @Vim Yes I did.. :D